# I need to get how many queries executed in particular datasets in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to know how many queries executed in mydatasets.

I tried myproject .information schema jobs  , but it shows all the datasets result

Comment: It doesn't make sense. A dataset is only a set of table, there is no value to know the query done "on a dataset"!

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of jobs by filtering the `dataset_id` and `job_type`. Then count the `job_id`. See approach below:

```sql
select 
  count(job_id) job_count,
  rt.dataset_id
from `your-project-id`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS, -- define your region
unnest(referenced_tables) rt
  where rt.dataset_id = "sandbox" -- define your dataset here
  and job_type = "QUERY"
group by rt.dataset_id
```

Output:

[image]

See reference https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs